# Find the degree and connected components?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let S be a set of n elements {1,2,.....,n} and G a graph with 2^n vertices, each vertex corresponding to a distinct subset of S. Two vertices are adjacent iff the symmetric difference of the corresponding sets has exactly 2 elements. Note: The symmetric difference of two sets R1 and  R2 is defined as (R1∖R2) ∪ (R2∖R1)

Every vertex in G has the same degree.

(i)What is the degree of a vertex in G?

(i)How many connected components does G have?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? You are given the fact that all vertices have the same degree. Think of a vertex whose degree is easy to find.

Comment: i did sir,but came to be incorrect.Can you give a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Since we know that each vertex has the same degree, the obvious candidate is the empty set vertex. The symmetric difference of the empty set and a given set A is just that same set A, so the empty set vertex is connected precisely to those vertices that represent subsets of size two.

As for connected components, consider even and odd sizes of subsets (including the empty set with a "size" of zero). If a set has even size then we can connect it to any other set of even size, like so:

We consider each set via the appropriate binary string, e.g. {1,2} would be 1100 when n = 4 and just 11 when n = 2. Note that taking the symmetric difference of two sets corresponds exactly to adding together their binary strings.

It is easy to see then that each such binary string is adjacent precisely to those binary strings which differ from it in exactly two places; this is simply a restatement of the formulation of G. So to get from any even size set to another we just change two digits at a time until we transform the first set's binary string to the second's. For instance, when n= 8, to get from {1,2} to {1,2,4,5,6,7} we change 11000000 to 11011110 via the following steps:

11000000 -> 11011000 -> 11011110

This corresponds to following the edges from {1,2} to {1,2,4,5} to {1,2,4,5,6,7}.

We can make the same argument for subsets of odd length, and since we always change exactly two digits of the binary strings by moving along an edge in G, we cannot get from an odd length subset to an even length subset.